# Узнать сумму итераций цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x, числа, суммирование

Программа отображает числа кратные 3 и 5. Вопрос: как реализовать программу, чтобы помимо отображения самих чисел, программа отображала сумму этих чисел?

```
b = int(input("Введите число: "))
for a in range(b):
    if a % 3 == 0 or a % 5 == 0:
        print(a)
        a -= 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
b = int(input("Введите число: "))

s = 0
for a in range(b):
    if a % 3 == 0 or a % 5 == 0:
        print(a)
        s += a
print(s)
```